# How to return cumulative totals per year including for years where there is no data

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a database in SQL Azure with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Years
(
    YearID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    YearName VARCHAR(8)
)

INSERT INTO Years (YearName)
VALUES ('2017-18'),('2018-19'),('2019-20'),('2020-21'),('2021-22'),('2022-23')

CREATE TABLE People
(
    PersonID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO People (FirstName)
VALUES ('Fred'), ('Bob'), ('Samit'), ('Kate')

CREATE TABLE WorkCategories 
(
    CatID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CatName VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO WorkCategories (CatName) 
VALUES ('Testing'), ('Examining'), ('Teaching'), ('Marking')

CREATE TABLE WorkDone
(
    WorkID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    PersonID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES People(PersonID),
    WorkCategory INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES WorkCategories(CatID),
    YearID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Years(YearID),
    HoursWorked INT
)

INSERT INTO WorkDone (PersonID, WorkCategory, YearID, HoursWorked)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 10), (1, 1, 2, 30), (1, 1, 3, 15),
       (1, 1, 6, 25), (1, 2, 1, 24), (1, 2, 4, 28), 
       (1, 2, 4, 28), (1, 2, 5, 20), (1, 2, 6, 10)
```

I want to be able to get a cumulative total of the work done, per category for each person for any given year.

So far, I have created this view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_TotalWorkDone
AS
    SELECT
        y.YearName,
        WorkInfo.PersonID, WorkInfo.CatName, 
        WorkInfo.YearID, WorkInfo.TotalHours,
        SUM(WorkInfo.TotalHours) OVER 
(PARTITION BY WorkInfo.PersonID, WorkInfo.CatName ORDER BY y.YearName DESC) AS TotalSinceDate
    FROM 
        Years y
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT
             wc.CatName, wd.PersonID, wd.YearID,
             SUM(wd.HoursWorked) AS TotalHours
         FROM 
             WorkCategories wc
         LEFT JOIN 
             WorkDone wd ON wc.CatID = wd.WorkCategory
         GROUP BY 
             wc.CatName, wd.PersonID, wd.YearID) WorkInfo ON y.YearID = WorkInfo.YearID
```

The results returned by my view are accurate, looking like this:

| YearName | PersonID | CatName | YearID | TotalHours | TotalSinceDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-23 | 1 | Examining | 6 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-22 | 1 | Examining | 5 | 20 | 30 |
| 2020-21 | 1 | Examining | 4 | 56 | 86 |
| 2017-18 | 1 | Examining | 1 | 24 | 110 |
| 2022-23 | 1 | Testing | 6 | 25 | 25 |
| 2019-20 | 1 | Testing | 3 | 15 | 40 |
| 2018-19 | 1 | Testing | 2 | 30 | 70 |
| 2017-18 | 1 | Testing | 1 | 10 | 80 |

However what I want is to be able to do is use the view to allow me to see how much work the selected person has done of each type since the specified year, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_TotalWorkDone 
WHERE PersonID=1 
AND  YearName='2018-19'
```

to get my answer.

The problem is that although I'll see the total testing done, I won't see anything for examining, because it happens that this person didn't do any examining in that year.

What I need, therefore, is to have each year reported, with the cumulative total back to that year, even if there are no records of the selected type for that year - so more like this (I've left out testing for the sake of brevity, but it should report all categories where any work has been done at any time in the period):

| YearName | PersonID | CatName | YearID | TotalHours | TotalSinceDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-23 | 1 | Examining | 6 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-22 | 1 | Examining | 5 | 20 | 30 |
| 2020-21 | 1 | Examining | 4 | 56 | 86 |
| 2019-20 | 1 | Examining | 4 | 0 | 86 |
| 2018-19 | 1 | Examining | 4 | 0 | 86 |
| 2017-18 | 1 | Examining | 1 | 24 | 110 |

Can anyone advise how best to do this please?

Comment: The data goes back about a decade currently, but is being added to each year. The idea is that the view will show cumulative totals back to the start of the data, and by querying that view, the user can say "How much work has person x done in this category since x year"? The view returns all the data, and the application using this view filters to the year requested by the user. Does that make sense? I just included a sample of the data, enough to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Perhaps this is my ignorance, but surely if I use the WHERE clause to specify the data required, the server is only going to send back the data required. I could, I guess, make this a table-valued function and then pass the required year as a parameter. But that doesn't resolve the basic issue of not getting any summary data for the specified year if no work was done in that year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (presumbly) want to `CROSS JOIN` your `Years`, `People` and `WorkCategories` tables, and then `LEFT JOIN` to your `WorkDone` table. Then you can use a windowed `SUM` to get the running total.

I have a `WHERE` in the below as your expected results are only for a specific person and category, however, if you removed those it would still work, generating a row for each distinct set of year, person and category.

```sql
SELECT Y.YearName,
       P.PersonID,
       WC.CatID,
       WC.CatName,
       Y.YearID,
       ISNULL(WD.HoursWorked,0) AS Totalhours,
       SUM(WD.HoursWorked) OVER (PARTITION BY P.PersonID, WC.CatName ORDER BY Y.YearName DESC
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS TotalSinceDate
FROM dbo.Years Y
     CROSS JOIN dbo.People P
     CROSS JOIN dbo.WorkCategories WC
     LEFT JOIN dbo.WorkDone WD ON Y.YearID = WD.YearID
                              AND P.PersonID = WD.PersonID
                              AND WC.CatID = WD.WorkCategory
WHERE P.PersonID = 1
  AND WC.CatName = 'Examining'
ORDER BY P.PersonID,
         WC.CatID,
         Y.YearName DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EXoGPAWw)

Answer (score 0):

You need a derived table for all options between years, person, categories

modify your view like so

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vw_TotalWorkDone
AS
    SELECT
        y.YearName,
        y.PersonID, y.CatName, 
        y.YearID, TotalHours=ISNULL(WorkInfo.TotalHours,0),
        ISNULL(SUM(WorkInfo.TotalHours) OVER 
            (   PARTITION BY WorkInfo.PersonID, WorkInfo.CatName 
                ORDER BY y.YearName DESC), 0) AS TotalSinceDate
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT  Y.*, P.* , W.*
        FROM    Years y
        OUTER APPLY People P
        OUTER APPLY WorkCategories W 
    ) y
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT
             wc.CatName, wd.PersonID, wd.YearID,
             SUM(wd.HoursWorked) AS TotalHours
         FROM 
             WorkCategories wc
         LEFT JOIN 
             WorkDone wd ON wc.CatID = wd.WorkCategory
         GROUP BY 
             wc.CatName, wd.PersonID, wd.YearID) WorkInfo   ON  y.YearID = WorkInfo.YearID 
                                                            AND y.PersonID = WorkInfo.PersonID
                                                            AND y.CatName   = WorkInfo.CatName
GO
```

output

[image]